# Which Visual Studio debugger features are missing from WinDbg?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, comparison, windbg

Are there any?

Answer (score 2):

A polished UI is a feature.  Windbg somewhat lacks this feature.  But that only matters when UI "bugs" slow me down, and that's not really very often.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the easier to use GUI -- it has many more debugging features than VS.

BTW, I highly recommend [Advanced Windows Debugging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321374460) to learn about it and other advanced debugging tools and techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Find-In-Files search.
But I really miss editing and the "compile" button :)